# How would you declare a large number in GMP?

Tags: c++, gmp

How would you declare a large number that is 128 bits in GMP with the `#include <gmp.h>`? This number is an integer.

Comment: Jarryd comments that `<gmp.h>` is the C definitions.  Did you want to use the C++ `<gmpxx.h>` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Use `mpz_set_str` to initialize to an ascii value.

```
mpz_t N;
mpz_init(N);
mpz_set_str(N, "55555555555555555555555555555");
```

Comment: The question is marked "C++". Surely `mpz_class n("555555");` would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sure, make your own answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: although he asks for how to do it with `#include <gmp.h>` which doesn't have the C++ definitions, so `mpz_class` wouldn't work.

Comment: so is it possible to do it with #include <gmp.h> - extremely noob first year in college

Comment: Yes, mine works if you `#include <gmp.h>`.  Kerrek SB's works if you `#include <gmpxx.h>`.

Comment: Or with C++11 and `gmpxx.h` you could write: `auto n = 5555555555555555555555_mpz;`.